# Map with overlay is not moving after zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a map which returns the LatLng by pixel on screen, therefore I need a OverlayView implemented within the map. Unfortunately with the OverlayView, there is an issue after zoom in or out. When dragging the map after zoom, it does return me a new LatLng, but the screen is still showing the same location.

I am not sure how to fix it but the issue will gone once I pan the map with the pan control, then I could drag the map no matter the zoom level.

can anybody give me an advise?

Thanks, 
Nick

Comment: A link to live code would be valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, just call panTo function in the "zoom_changed" event.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mymap, "zoom_changed", function() {
mymap.panTo(mymap.getCenter());
});
```

The map may not move smoothing because the panTo function is only called by zoom_change event unfortunately, so just call the panTo function after the map is initialized. Then the map could be moving around and different zoom level.